# Installing Grunt js on 13.04

Tags: nodejs, grunt

How does one install grunt on Ubuntu 13.04?

I've attempted to install it via NPM:

```
sudo npm install -g grunt
```

Then when i run grunt:

```
grunt
```

But it doesn't seem to work it throws an error:

```
path.js:313
        throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.resolve must be strings');
              ^ TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
    at Object.exports.resolve (path.js:313:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt:13:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Here's some information about what version of node i have:

```
$ npm -v                                                                      
1.3.8
```

Comment: Did you really mean to run the command `sudo npm install -g grunt $ grunt`? Shouldn't `sudo npm install -g grunt` be sufficient? I think the `$` isn't valid syntax for the `npm install` command.

Comment: I'm illustrating the prompt. Sorry no `$` needed. Also, was that the reason why you downvoted? Sorry i can change that if you'd like.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250437/grunt-throw-new-typeerrorarguments-to-path-resolve-must-be-strings

Comment: You should avoid using sudo with npm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the error occurs when there are two versions of grunt.

To find out if you have two versions of grunt installed you run in CLI:

`where grunt` or `which grunt`

If you see more than one version of grunt:

```
/usr/local/bin/grunt
/usr/bin/grunt
/usr/local/bin/grunt
/usr/bin/grunt
```

Then you just remove one of them:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/grunt
```

Wrote a [post on this](http://hire.chrisjlee.net/node/185) for more information.

Comment: I don't seem to have that `where` command available.

Comment: @tutuca you can use which grunt instead

Comment: oh, I know... but `where` was interesting :P

Comment: you can use this command whereis grunt instead of where

Answer (score 11):

I believe you want:  `npm install -g grunt-cli` which installs the command line tool.  You install grunt (and modules) locally in each project

Docs here to back up my words; http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Answer (score 3):

I just installed grunt from PPA.  Here is a full list of steps that I had to take to get a working grunt build:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nodejs
# remove a conflicting install of npm that I had tried earlier
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo npm install -g grunt grunt-cli grunt-contrib-clean grunt-replace grunt-contrib-concat grunt-contrib-watch grunt-contrib-jasmine grunt-contrib-connect grunt-saucelabs grunt-gitinfo
```